# Write to Kafka from a Dask worker

Tags: apache-kafka, dask

I'm trying to figure out how I can write to Kafka from Dask. We are tied to using the Confluent library. Dask attempts to pickle the producer to send it to the worker, but because of a lazy instantiation, it fails with an error. I was able to come up with the following solution, but it seems like a hack.

```py
def get_producer(config):
    w = get_worker()
    if hasattr(w, 'producer'):
        return w.producer

    import confluent_kafka as ck
    w.producer = getattr(ck, 'Producer')(config)
    return w.producer
```

The `hasattr` workaround will create the producer on the dask worker when submitted. This code also ties the producer to the worker in order to keep the connection open for streaming.

I'm hoping that someone who is more of a Dask expert than I am has some helpful advice.

Comment: What's the error you get? I don't the hasattr is causing lazy initialization. You could get if the worker is None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a bit of a hack, yes, but it's also fine.

You might also consider re-creating the producer in every task, then writing data, and then closing that producer.  If it doesn't take too long to create a producer relative to the amount of time it takes to write a partition of data then this might be a decent solution.  It's slightly less efficient, but probably more robust/secure/mature.